# Move to end of selection in MS Excel (2003)

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2003, selection

I have a large set of data that I update regularly by copy/pasting and overwriting old data. I do this for 10k-15k records at a time. Once I have pasted, I manually scroll down to the last line of data that was just pasted in order to mark/highlight that part of the file so it is easier to pick up there on the next import.

i.e. I have 20k total rows, I have pasted (and thus have an active selection of) 10k rows, starting at 5k, and ending at 15k (in VBA: `Range(A5000:F15000)`).

I know that if I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd>, I can move to the last row of ALL the data (up to any spaces that may be present in the selected column), and I use these kinds of shortcuts regularly.

**Is there a keyboard shortcut or other simple method I can use to jump to the last row of the *CURRENT SELECTION* (as opposed to the last row of all data)?**

<sub>*I am very familiar with VBA and how to program this kind of process (which is probably ultimately easier), but at this point I just haven't gotten around to creating a macro to do this.</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.  This will keep your selection but move the active cell to the end of the selection.

Comment: beat me to it! I let me answer sit unposted for too long.

Comment: I just want to point out too that, following that logic, `<Shift>+<Tab>` also works!

Answer (score 2):

Do this using `BOTTOM-UP` Approach

### Steps to follow:

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN ARROW</kbd> continueously
2. Now you have reached to the last row of the excel sheet
3. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>UP ARROW</kbd> to reach to the last row of the record

### UPDATE:

Use this short-cut key:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN ARROW</kbd>

Comment: But I don't want the last row of all the data, I want the last row of the selection, which ends somewhere in the middle of the whole block. i.e. I have 20k total rows, I have pasted (and thus have a selection of) 10k rows, starting at 5k, and ending at 15k. How can I jump to line 15k (the last of the selection)?

Comment: @Gaffi: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for you assistance, however this is still not what I am looking for. `<CTRL>+<SHIFT>+<DOWN ARROW>` will *select* that range, but I already have my selection. I want to move the cursor/screen to the last line of the current selection.

Comment: @Gaffi: with this approach, scroll will move till end of your selection. After that, use mouse to click on the last row.

Comment: I just tried this. What happens is all the remaining rows of data are simply **added** to my current selection, and the screen moves down past the end of the current selection.

Answer (score 2):

Jumping corner-to-corner inside the selected range:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

https://www.excelcampus.com/keyboard-shortcuts/jump-to-last-cell-selected-range/

Comment: Very interesting. Not quite as good as the currently selected answer (2x activations vs. 1x), but this still works. Thanks for the new tip!

Answer (score 0):

Shift+downarrow gets you to the bottom of your selection set **AND adds the next cell also**.  So if you are in Column A you highlight row 1 thru 1000, apply the method stated to jump to cell A1001.  So go back up 1 cell for your actual end point of the original selection set.

Answer (score -2):

Shift+CTRL+downarrow works if you would like to select last last row with records. But it does not work if there are spaces in the rows.

Comment: The OP has stated multiple times that this is not what he wants.